# Setting background for fragment

Tags: android, background, fragment

I have a list fragment and a details fragment in a xml layout which is set as the layout of an activity. How can I set a background image for each fragment. If I am doing it in xml like `android:background=@drawable/anyimage` it shows an error. I searched but didn't get what I needed, so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Please poet the screen shot of the fragments where you want the background. Or r u using list as fragment ?

Comment: yes i am using ListFragment and using setListAdapter().Any help!!!!

Comment: It was not shwoing error.I mean if i am setting background then it is not displaying any image in background.

Comment: You can always do it programatically within onCreateView().

Answer (score 0):

In my case the image file was blank and I saved it wrong. Might want to double check.

Edit:
Ok, actually, putting android:background in a <fragment> doesn't work, but it will if you put it in the top level element of a layout the fragment inflates.

Comment: dont u think this should be a comment ?

Comment: Maybe. I had the same problem, and there were no answers for this and similar questions.

Comment: yes...this problem is not solved.luckily i got out of that project. ;)